# How to check crash logs in XCODE in iphone sdk

Tags: ios5, memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode4.3, symbolicatecrash

i'm new to the iPhone application development, when i'm running my application in device application is crashing and giving following log in organizer

here is the log report :

```
Incident Identifier: 23B91310-BCEC-497B-821A-8CF8E709ACF7
CrashReporter Key:   3202fd13cd0c5e4ab0706615fabf36ebc9396206
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: Sat Jul  9 00:59:43 PDT 2011; root:xnu-    1735.47~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2012-08-22 10:45:15 +0530
Time since snapshot: 54 ms

Free pages:        588
Wired pages:       16800
Purgeable pages:   38
Largest process:   BJS

 Processes
     Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
         BJS <312d3dae46e433f9982c26738e40060b>   36928 (jettisoned) (active)
  debugserver <919dbac91c0e3133a517d6c7a99e667e>     184
    SCHelper <f8cf7ee034ac3991a79d8c78e435c1e7>     131
  Preferences <cbdecd3d02e031e48e9675235a51306c>    1045 (jettisoned)
  springboardservi <5ab19f16a3973514b6d7d62201d6abde>     309
   syslog_relay <344c7c41bec5360aae33f4fd412ea95f>      94
  notification_pro <698dca6c4cba390a8017315bd25f18f8>     112
   syslog_relay <344c7c41bec5360aae33f4fd412ea95f>      97
  notification_pro <698dca6c4cba390a8017315bd25f18f8>     108
        ptpd <6072e173aed83310b9b7589a70a24b0b>     580
    talkmeim <eb62d6230d5f304f9819c6aebc2d2298>    1141 (jettisoned)
         lsd <3fafa485b73836acb973d50feabd963a>     248
     notifyd <9966082842de313a8e05a001c783faf4>     126
    BTServer <01550e9527353eecae41ebee0f889603>     308
  CommCenter <7d9446365b4836968ae361626ef8f939>     271
        misd <8f94228bddf8342994baf5ca9af1154d>     154
 SpringBoard <5c55c6fba0843b0e924e116413b8c9d4>    4143 (active)
  accessoryd <d30e340e36df356bbde3347a6ed1ef87>     148
        apsd <47ffc9ce9f84371588bd3f937aaa20bb>     285
     configd <a6d457fca42732d9ba809d03a2b3e3ae>     401
 fairplayd.N81 <144f0ff89c123fa5a1cfa40da72fb024>     165
     imagent <9e0b26bad4a538a5b0e5e5ee7eeeb7be>     234
   locationd <9088e845dcbe37d890c8758655bf34c6>     685
  mDNSResponder <caf94711b8093dc5bc5736306f8ae818>     198
  mediaremoted <21af791e80823c9f90f0be2b77a3d885>     199
 mediaserverd <c731263114c33a07aef7bccdcf667271>     643
   lockdownd <1c7f2b41744c35dc92f679e90a73e240>     268
     syslogd <d81669e7bdb93f9b9012020beac826f4>     100
 usbethernetshari <25130d2f9a0334e3ae28780250343144>     105
     launchd <e2d41e07a0743a089eadbae765709c82>      84

**End**
```

can any one pls help how to track the log report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an application crash, so much as application termination: iOS has a mechanism called Jetsam (or, officially, memory status) which "jettisons" (i.e. throws out) the largest process (in terms of memory) when physical memory is low. This is a necessary measure because iOS has no swap. In your log, which is generated by jetsam, you can see a list of all the processes which were active, and BJS - which has been thrown out. The format is :

```
Incident Identifier: Automatically generated GUID for Apple
CrashReporter Key:   Hash, probably of GUID
Hardware Model:      i-Device stepping (4,1 is 4th gen iPod in your case)
OS Version:          Version of iOS
Kernel Version:      Kernel version, as per uname -a
Date:                ... figure this one out
Time since snapshot: How much time has passed - the snapshot may be "dated"

Free pages:        How many free pages of RAM remain. Page = 4k
Wired pages:       How many resident pages
Purgeable pages:   How many pages MAY be freed, if all else fails
Largest process:   The culprit

 Processes
     Name                 UUID                    Count resident pages
         BJS <312d3dae46e433f9982c26738e40060b>   36928 (jettisoned) (active)
```

Table, as per column header, where (jettisoned) implies jetsam killed you. (active) implies you were the foreground app.

Hope this helps, (if it doesn't - comment or ask me directly)

Comment: great help. should be answer. I have encountered this kind of crash these days. besides pages you mentioned, active pages,Throttled pages are also listed in crash log. Could you explain them ? Thank you very much.